# How can i do gradient-color to <i> tag?

Tags: css

how can I add a gradient color to <i> tag?
i can to do background color with linear-gradient, but it works for background

i want to get gradient for filling;

```
.my_div i {
  background: linear-gradient (bla-bla-bla)
}
```

```
.my_div {
  color: *something*
}
```

but linear-gradient does not work for color-option

thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<i>` tag is an inline tag for italic text, if you want to add a color gradient to it, you can use this trick that requires webkit:

```
i {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #0000ff, #ff0000);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

The result looks like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANFgK.png)